# how can i insert record in 2 tables at a time using parametrized sql query and vb script in asp classic?

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, parameter-passing

I'm using ASP Classic and VBScript. I have 2 tables. The first table contains columns like *username* and *password* and the second contains columns like *name* and *email*. Both tables are related (`table1.id = table2.Id`).

How can I insert a record in 2 tables at a time using parametrized SQL query. My code is below.

```vb
<%
'for table 1  
Dim objRS, objCmd, str

Set objCmd  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

str = "insert into admin (Ausr, Apwd)values(?,?)"

With objCmd
    .ActiveConnection = MM_connDUdirectory_STRING
    .CommandText = str
    .CommandType = adCmdText

    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa1", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(username)))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa2", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(password)))

    .Parameters("@sa1").Value = username
    .Parameters("@sa2").Value = password
end with 
Set objRS = objCmd.Execute()

%>
```

For table2, I faced problems in tracing the inserted record's ID from above. In below code I'm not able to retrieve ID:

```vb
<%
'for table 2
Dim objRS1, objCmd1, str1

Set objCmd1  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs1   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

str1 = "insert into detail (ID, Aname, Aemail)values(?,?,?)"

With objCmd1
    .ActiveConnection = MM_connDUdirectory_STRING
    .CommandText = str1
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa3", adInteger, adParamInput, ,ID)) 
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa4", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(vname)))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa5", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(email)))

    .Parameters("@sa3").Value = ID
    .Parameters("@sa4").Value = vname
    .Parameters("@sa5").Value = email
end with 
Set objRS1 = objCmd1.Execute()

%>
```

Please help me to solve the above issue or if there is any other way to insert a record in 2 tables using parametrized query, please tell me.

@Tomalak as per your code, I tried to do with it using the below tables

```
<%
Function InsertAdmin(Ausr, Apwd, Acdate, ATid, Astate, Acity, Acenterid, Aname, gender, Acontact, Aemail, ACreatedBy, suspend, allow, approve, Staff_Aid, Staff_EId, Staff_Fname, Staff_Add, Staff_Padd, Staff_Edu, Staff_doc) 

Dim objRS, objCmd, str

Set objCmd  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With objCmd
    .ActiveConnection = MM_connDUdirectory_STRING
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = Join(Array( _
        "DECLARE @id INT", _
        "insert into admin (Ausr, Apwd, Acdate, ATid, Astate, Acity, Acenterid, Aname, gender, Acontact, Aemail, ACreatedBy, suspend, allow, approve)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", _
        "SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()", _
        "insert into Staff_detail (Staff_Aid, Staff_EId, Staff_Fname, Staff_Add, Staff_Padd, Staff_Edu, Staff_doc)values(@id,?,?,?,?,?,?)"), vbNewLine)


.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa1", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(StrUsr)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa2", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(md5(StrPwd))))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa3", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(dt)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa4", adInteger, adParamInput, ,atypeid))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa5", adInteger, adParamInput, ,StrState))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa10", adInteger, adParamInput, ,StrCity))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa11", adInteger, adParamInput, ,StrCenter))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa118", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(stname)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa119", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(stgender)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa110", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(stcontact)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa111", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(stemail)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa6", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(Request.Cookies("Vape")("User"))))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa7", adInteger, adParamInput, ,susp))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa8", adInteger, adParamInput, ,allowd)) 
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa9", adInteger, adParamInput, ,approved)) 
'.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa101", adInteger, adParamInput, ,@ID))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa102", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(stcode)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa103", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(stfname)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa104", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(stadd)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa105", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(stpadd)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa106", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(stedu)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@sa107", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(stdoc)))

End With
Set objRS = objCmd.Execute() 
End Function
call InsertAdmin(StrUsr, md5(StrPwd), dt, 5, StrState, StrCity, StrCenter, stname, stgender, stcontact, stemail, a_name, 0, 1, 0, stcode, stfname, stadd, stpadd, stedu, stdoc) 
%>
```

But it's showing an error saying:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01C2)
>   Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'InsertAdmin'

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187342.aspx. Easiest way -  using `SELECT @@identity` after first `insert` statement.

Comment: **NEVER** use `@@IDENTITY`.  That's bad advice. Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx.

Comment: I would be tempted to just do this all in a stored procedure that way you don't have to worry about the code.

Comment: @VMC  can you show me how to retrieve @@identity in above code?

Comment: @lokeshpurohit: **NO** don't use `@@INDENTITY` follow the link in my comment and read about `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Comment: Paul, you right: using SCOPE_IDENTITY() much better.

Comment: @Paul i am not using store procedure. can you help me to do in vb script as above written code?

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` is not scope safe - if someone else runs a query before your query picks up the identity strange things happen.

Comment: Lankymart is right above - you *should* use stored procedures - they're much faster, safer, and a better programming method than embedded SQL.

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will work in roughly the same way as `@@IDENTITY` and can be used in embedded code.

Comment: @paul ok then let me try :)

Comment: @VMV: Apologies for being so blunt there.

Comment: Why are both your tables called "admin"? That's hardly possible.

Comment: @Tomalak sorry 2nd table is "detail" which is edited in above code too

Comment: Okay. Be advised that storing plain text passwords in a database is a very bad practice and you really should not do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use a single function that does the insert in one step. This one returns the ID of the newly inserted row:

```vb
Function InsertAdmin(username, password, vname, email) 
    With Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        .ActiveConnection = MM_connDUdirectory_STRING
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = Join(Array( _
            "DECLARE @id INT", _
            "INSERT INTO admin (Ausr, Apwd) VALUES (?, ?)", _
            "SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()", _
            "INSERT INTO detail (ID, Aname, Aemail) VALUES (@id, ?, ?)", _
            "SELECT @id NewId" _
        ), vbNewLine)

       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, , Len(username), username)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, , Len(password), password)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, , Len(vname), vname)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, , Len(email), email)

       With .Execute
           InsertAdmin = .Fields("NewId").Value
       End With
   End With 
End Function
```

Use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` to make extra plus sure the insert happens successfully or not at all.

Alternatively you could simply merge the two tables into one. I don't see a good reason for keeping two separate tables that have a 1:1 relation for this use case.

Comment: @Lankymart What exactly did you change in your edit? \*confused\*

Comment: [Syntax Highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) - `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` [See the revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25523562/revisions) (Use the markdown view)??

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't pay attention to the color differences.

Comment: It grates on me when I'm looking at code and the wrong keywords are being highlighted, have to change it. :)

Comment: Well, as long it *looks consistent* I don't care if all the PascalCase keywords show up in blue, but I can see what you mean.

Comment: Should your `With` statement not be `Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")`?

Comment: It's not just that it's identifying comments and strings correctly, if you're used to coding in an IDE to tend to expect it. It also helps find issues with string's not being terminated correctly in code snippets etc.

Comment: @Lankymart It should be `Command`, of course. Copy/paste glitch on my end.

Comment: @Tomalak i have pasted real code in above but its showing error.

Comment: Just a thought, but if it says "Wrong number of arguments" maybe you are using the wrong number of arguments? ;-)